# Angular2 - GET 400 disabling my observable.subscribe with interval

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have app where i have function `get()` which returning me `Observable.interval(1000)` with http GET.

In app.component I subscribe this Observable and printing on screen some values from GET.

Everythings works fine until the get response returns 400 - the server send 404 from time to time- its normally. But when i recive 400, my subscribe stops working.
Screen show only last valuse and stop "refreshing"

Here is some code:

```
getAct(symbol:string): Observable<Act> {

return Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .flatMap(() => {
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map((res: Response):Act => (res.json()))
      .catch(err =>  {
        return Observable.throw(err); 
      });
  });
```

}

And here is code which subscribe:

```
this.actSub = this.actService
  .getAct(this.symbol)
  .subscribe(
    act => {
        console.log("ok");
        this.act = act;            
      }
    },
    err => {console.warn(err);},
    ()=>console.log("Done")
  );
```

So, if I run my app in console i have this:
[image]

So the program run fine - 29 get succesfull, but when it recive 400 its stops, and there where no more "ok".

Where is the problem? Is my getAct() wrong, or maybe when i subscribe I code something bad?

Please help, I tried to repair this, but i couldn't.

Comment: This is normal behavior. An observable stops emitting value after it either completes or errors (as is the case with a 4** HTTP response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several RxJS operators to handle errors.

The easiest would be to use [retry()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retry):

```ts
return this.http.get(url)
  .retry()
  .map(res => res.json());
```

This is an agressive strategy as it will re-subscribe to the original observable (`this.http.get(...)`) *as soon as* a request fails. You could end up hitting the server really hard.

You might wanna use [retryWhen()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen) instead, which will let you introduce a slight delay before retrying, e.g.:

```ts
return this.http.get(url)
  .retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(2000))  // 2-second delay before retrying
  .map(res => res.json());
```

Answer (score 1):

I can make something like this,but i think it's really bad solution.

```
  get(){
        this.actSub = this.actService
          .getAct(this.symbol)
          .subscribe(
            act => {
                console.log("ok");
                this.act = act;            
              }
            },
            err => {
                console.warn(err);
                this.get();
            },
            ()=>console.log("Done")
          );
    }
```